# What's the type of std :: move?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

This code works as expected (online [here](http://ideone.com/67QJ4)). 
At the end `v` is empty and `w` is not empty as it has pilfered the contents of `v`.

```
    vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(1);
    cout << "v.size(): " << v.size() << endl;
    auto vp = move(v);
    vector<int> w(vp);
    cout << "w.size(): " << w.size() << endl;
    cout << "v.size(): " << v.size() << endl;
```

But if I replace `auto vp=move(v)` with

```
    vector<int> && vp = move (v);
```

Then it doesn't move. Instead it copies and both vectors are non-empty at the end. As shown [here](http://ideone.com/8v8qb).

**Clarification:** More specifically, what is the auto-derived type of `vp`? If it's not `vector<int> &&`, then what else could it be? Why do the two examples give different results despite being so similar?

**Extra**: I also tried this, and it still copied instead of moving

```
    std :: remove_reference< vector<int> > :: type && vp = move(v);
```

Comment: [`move` returns `std::remove_reference<T>::type&&`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move)

Comment: Indeed, but `remove_reference` on `vector<int>` just gives us `vector<int>`, as far as I can see.

Comment: I tried `std :: remove_reference< vector<int> > :: type && vp = move(v);` and it doesn't work either. It copies, not moves.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Edit for OP's clarification**: the `auto`-derived type of `move(v)` is `vector<int>`. See [C++11 "auto" semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542873/c11-auto-semantics).

The 1st example does this:

```
move 'v' into 'vp'
copy 'vp' into 'w'
```

and the 2nd example does this:

```
set 'vp' as rvalue-reference of 'v'
copy 'vp' (which is 'v') into 'w'
```

---

What `std:move` does is simply casting a type to an rvalue (See [What is std::move(), and when should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413470/what-is-stdmove)). Therefore, in

```
vector<int>&& vp = move(v);
```

it's just setting the rvalue-reference `vp` to `v` and do nothing else. Also, an rvalue-reference is an lvalue (it has a name), so

```
vector<int> w(vp);
```

will call the copy constructor to copy `vp` (which is `v`) into `w`.

It will call the move constructor if you make `vp` an rvalue ([Example](http://ideone.com/XoexY)):

```
vector<int> w(move(vp))
```

You may want to read this: [*C++ Rvalue References Explained*](http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_01.html).

Comment: This doesn't really explain why one way works but the other doesn't.

Comment: But it's not calling the copy constructor in the first example. `auto vp = move(v); vector<int> w(vp)` works (the data is pilfered). Why does this work? What is the auto-derived type of vp?

Comment: @AaronMcDaid: It *is* calling the copy constructor, just not calling `v`'s. See update.

Comment: Looking back on my own question from two years ago.  I can see that I was under the impression that `move` actually did something and had side effects.  I also assumed that the `auto` type would be a reference.  Wrong on both counts.

Answer (score 2):

In the first case:

```
auto vp = move(v);
```

is equivalent to:

```
vector<int> vp = move(v);
```

This invokes the move constructor, since `move(v)` has type `vector<int>&&`, hence `vp` ends up pilfering the contents of `v`.

In the second case:

```
vector<int>&& vp = move(v);
```

just makes `vp` an r-value reference to `v`. This doesn't result in the move constructor or copy constructor being called, and nothing is pilfered.

Answer (score 1):

```
auto vp = move(v);
```

Is creating a new `vector<int>` and calling it's move constructor:

```
vector(const vector<T>&& other);
```

Which will steal the contents of `v`.

So type of 'vp' is simply `vector<int>` .. no references involved:

```
vector<int> vp;
```

It's 'moving' the internals .. not the actual vector itself.

So `&vp` will be different to `&v` .. but the contents will move across.