# auto variable and its type

Tags: c++, c++11, auto

I found in a post how to delete elements from a container using an iterator. While iterating:

```
for(auto it = translationEvents.begin(); it != translationEvents.end();)
    {
        auto next = it;
        ++next; // get the next element
        it->second(this); // process (and maybe delete) the current element
        it = next; // skip to the next element
    }
```

Why is `auto` used without the type in `auto next = it;`?

I use VS10,not  C++11 !

Comment: See [C++11 type inference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Type_inference)

Comment: VS10 has C++11 on  by default. So, you do use C++11.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`auto` has a different meaning in C++11 than it did before. In earlier standards, `auto` was a storage specifier for automatic storage duration - the typical storage an object has where it is destroyed at the end of its scope. In C++11, the `auto` keyword is used for type deduction of variables. The type of the variable is deduced from the expression being used to initialise it, much in the same way template parameters may be deduced from the types of a template function's arguments.

This type deduction is useful when typing out ugly long types has no benefit. Often, the type is obvious from the initialiser. It is also useful for variables whose type might depend on which instantiation of a template it appears in.

Many C++11 features are supported by default in VC10 and `auto` is one of them.

Comment: what ? its supported in vc++2010 ? i didn't know that

Comment: Does this mean that auto no longer handles storage duration, or merely that it has increased what it does?

Answer (score 5):

It is a short-hand in newer versions of C++ that allows us to avoid the clunky iterator notation, since the compiler is able to infer what the actual type is supposed to be.

Answer (score 4):

It's called [Type Inference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#Type_inference), see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542873/c11-auto-semantics) for details. New in C++11, and intended to simplify many long and unnecessary codes, especially for iterators and function bindings.

Answer (score 3):

This is called [type inference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Type_inference). The type of the auto variable is deduced by the type of the initializer.

E.g., this reduces the amount to type for large and complicated template types.