# Using auto in C++ Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, mfc

In my Single Document Application I have this situation:

```
 class CObj
 {
 public:
      int m_nValue;
 // Rest of class implementation
 };
 typedef std::vector<CObj> CObjects;
 typedef std::unordered_map<double, CObjects> CObjects_2;
 typedef std::map<CString, CObjects_2> CObjects_3;

 class CMyDoc : public CDocument
 {
 protected:
      CObjects_3   m_Data;
 public:
      inline CObjects_3 & Data()
      {
           return m_Data;
      }
 }

 // Somewhere in the program:
 //...
 // Assuming that all keys exist:
 CObjects_3 & non_auto_data = pValidDocPointer->Data();
 non_auto_data[_T("Key")][3.0][0].m_nValue = 10;
 auto auto_data = m_pValidDocPointer->Data();
 auto_data[_T("Key")][3.0][0].m_nValue = 20;
 //...
```

Now, if I understood well how keyword auto works, I expect that

```
pValidDocPointer->m_Data[_T("Key")][3.0][0].m_nValue
```

will have a value of 20, but I see 10.
Is that a Visual Studio bug or it is correct? If correct: what I misunderstood in auto keyword functioning?

Comment: you want auto &

Comment: If this is the answer, please write down below so I can accept. Btw this is no-sense to me.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542873/c11-auto-semantics

Comment: @IssamTP You may feel as you do, but it is intended behavior. If it wasn't so, how would specify that you want to return the copy of the variable, and not a reference to it, in the following case: `auto f () {static int a = 5; return a;}`?

Comment: @IssamTP if you want `auto` to deduce references too, you can use `decltype(auto)`. Plain auto will act just like a deduced template parameter.