# auto/ decltype Error I'm curious why the code doesn't work. (E0252)

Tags: c++, auto, decltype

```
int main()
{
    double x[3] = { 1,2,3 };

    auto n1 = x[0];

    decltype(n1) d1 = n1;
    decltype(n1) d2;   // ok


    decltype(x[0]) d3; // error
}
```

I am a beginner user who uses stack overflow for the first time. An error occurs when using the type in the following code, and I want to know why. I need the help of smart people.

Comment: If you don't tag your question with the programming language you are using, it is very unlikely to be seen by anyone. I only noticed it by accident. Please tag the language next time. I have added `c++` for you this time.

Comment: When asking about compiler errors, please include those errors in the question. A numeric error code is not enough, nobody remembers those.

Answer (score 3):

When `decltype` is applied to an expression which is not only an unparenthesized name, it does not only use the type of the expression, but also its value category.

If the value category is lvalue, then it will produce a lvalue reference, if it is xvalue, it will produce a rvalue reference and if it is prvalue, it will produce a non-reference.

In your case `x[0]` is a lvalue and therefore `decltype(x[0])` is `double&`, not `double`. The variable `d3` is then a reference, which always must have an initializer in its definition, which it doesn't have here.

`decltype(n1)` is different. If the operand of `decltype` is just an unparanthesized name, it will result in the type with which the name is declared, so here `double`.

If you used `decltype((n1))` instead, the previous value category rules would apply and it would be `double&` again.

Answer (score 0):

The answer above is pretty clear. But for you to remember it easily, I would like to think `auto` and `decltype` as such: `auto` preserves the minimum information, while `decltype` preserves maximum information.

So if you don't use auto, then you can actually write:
`double n1 = x[0]`, or
`double &n1 = x[0]`.
As said, `auto` preserves the minimum information, so your code is evaluated to the first one.

`decltype` preserves maximum information, so `decltype(x[0])` is equivalent to
`double &`, which is why you cannot write your last statement as you must initialize a reference.

Comment: [C++11 "auto" semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542873/c11-auto-semantics)